# c# unicode chars in serialization

Tags: c#, serialization

I've got a list of dictionaries:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> list= new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

I need to serialize this list to add it in another dictionary of strings, I did it in this way:

```
JavaScriptSerializer javascriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string serializedArticles = javascriptSerializer.Serialize(list);
body.Add("Rows", serializedArticles);
```

It works but the char ' is stored as \u0027, how I can fix this?

Comment: That's because the single quote character is protected.

Comment: @PoulBak is there any way to fix it? I need the single quote and not the code

Comment: May be you can replace it with \\', that should be legal javascript